# webpack error unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to debug this error for hours couldn't find what's wrong with it. Strange error!
app.js

```
var React = require('react');

var app = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<h1>Hello World from Reach</h1>);
    }
})

module.export = app;
```

app-client.js

```
var React = require('react');
var App = require('./components/app');

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

The error

```
ERROR in ./app-client.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/alice/reactjs/app-client.js: Unexpected token (4:13)
2 | var app = require('./components/app');
3 | 
4 | React.render(<app/>, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Comment: what in ./components/app ?

Comment: should `app` be `App`?

Comment: replace `var app = require('./components/app')` to `var App = require('./components/app')`; and 
`<app/>` -> `<App />` accordingly

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko I thought that was the error but i still got the same error.

Comment: maybe your path wrong ? Do you  have  './components/app' and not  './components/app.jsx'   ?

Comment: show us your ./components/app as  @AndriyIvaneyko suggested. And use ReactDom.render() instead of React.render(), React.render() is deprecated.

Comment: @Mark I've updated ur answer. I was following a video tutorial, it's working for the instructor.

Comment: @Mark tried ReactDom.render(), the error doesn't resolved.

Comment: ReactDom.render() won't fix it, I just wanted to let you know, I'm looking at your code now.

Comment: What's in your web pack config?

Comment: @Mark http://pastebin.com/tztKDaya

Comment: @AlienXu Does my answer works for you?If no how have you  fixed problem?\

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error. Within creating class in app.js file replace `render()` to `render: function()`
So your `app` assignment should looks like code below:

```
var app = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<h1>Hello World from Reach</h1>);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in your webpack.config.js. In order to successfully build jsx and ES6 you need to add more loaders. Here is my suggested js loader config, see if it works for you.

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {                 
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
        }
},
```

The es2015 preset [handles ES2015 features, you need to install via npm as described here.](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/)
You definitely need the [react preset to parse jsx.](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/)
[Stage 0 handles some of the latest javascript features.](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/)

Make sure you install these via npm as described in the links and change your web pack.config.js.